# AngularJS - reusing controller with different service on same page

Tags: angularjs

in AngularJS I can define a controller for a section on the page. I can have a single page with multi-controllers.

```
<div ng-controller="ThisSectionController">
    .... 

</div>
<div ng-controller="ThatSectionController">
    ....
</div>
```

I can reuse a controller while sending a different configuration with ng-init

```
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="i = 1">  
    {{ i }}
</div>
<div ng-controller="MyController" ng-init="i =2" >
    {{ i }}
</div>
```

This will output 1 and 2 as you expect it.

My question is - How can I reuse a controller and configure it to use a different service?

Comment: + 1 - Did not know about ng-init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a directive that injects `$controller` and use it in the linking function to instanciate the controller you want on a map of its instanciation arguments :

```
$controller("MyController", { $scope: scope, myService: myService})
```

`scope` is the scope variable of the linking function and `myService` is the service you can retrieve with the `$injector` service.

Comment: Let me see if I got it right - I pass a string on the directive to specify the service name, and then I use some $injector API something like `$injector.getService(serviceName)`? So my directive will look something like this: `<my-dir controller-name="MyController" service-name="MyService"> ... </my-dir>` and this should replace the previous `<div ng-controller="MyController">` right?

Comment: Actually - now that I think about it - why not use $injector in the Controller and then pass service name in ng-init?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724832/angularjs-runtime-dependency-injection

Comment: You are right, it's a quite better approach ! Actually I presented the controller unit test approach to mock a service.