# Inject module dependency (like plugin) only if needed AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, angularjs-injector

I have 2 pages (I don't use the `angular`'s `routing` - This constraint).

In one of them I want to use the directive [`ui-grid`](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro) like in this demo:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.grid']);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myData = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is if there is a way to not inject the `ui-grid` dependency to the app in any case but only when I need it.

Something like:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
   app.$inject('ui-grid');
});
```

**Update**

I tried to do:

```
var ui_grid = $injector.get('ui-grid');
```

But I've got an error:

> Unknown provider: ui-gridProvider <- ui-grid
>
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/unpr?p0=ui-gridProvider%20%3C-%20ui-grid

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13724832 ?

Comment: @AT no it's not. My question is about using another module and his directives in the `view` not in the `controller`.

Comment: I assume also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29617903/conditionally-inject-angular-module-dependency & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721530/conditional-injection-of-a-service-in-angularjs. In Mosh’s case it’s a directive not a service

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff No, it's not. Did you see my comment to A T? It's the same. I don't need to inject a `service` or `factory`. I need to inject a module. Can you share with me a working fiddle with solution like in your attached question?

Comment: @MoshFeu I don’t think injector would help you with modules indeed, can’t help here. Note that in your second code block example you’re showing how you want to inject a _directive_, not a _module_. It’s in general confusing as to what is the goal that you’re trying to achieve.

Comment: @AntonStrogonoff ya I know, I just want to mention that I tried like _A t_'s answer so people will not offer solutions like this. Thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Why not make your app dependencies a variable that is a array, then just based on some conditions (such as which page) decide what modules to add to the app? You can not directly inject modules into a controller as you are trying to do, since the directive in the view needs that module to already be loaded.

Comment: Thanks @jjbskir that's what I do now. I'm looking for the the "right" way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Core Angular API does not provide this feature. [ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad) is the popular library for lazy loading of modules and components in Angular.

You can find more info on their page:
[https://oclazyload.readme.io](https://oclazyload.readme.io/)

or the GitHub repository:
https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

Answer (score 3):

Core Angular API does provide this feature, simply use 'requires' property of module @ Properties section @ https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/type/angular.Module

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

//Page 1 JS
//change below statement as per requirement in different pages
app.requires = ['ui.grid'];
app.controller('mainCtrl1', function($scope) {

}

//Page 2 JS
app.requires = ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.calendar'];
app.controller('mainCtrl2', function($scope) {

}
```

ocLazyLoad is also good solution, but I guess 'requires' property will solve your problem without much effort.

Answer (score 1):

In my project I dynamically bootstrap angular modules using [`angular.bootstrap()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap). I have several pages with different sets of modules.

**Example:**

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('WelcomeController', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Welcome!';
});
angular.bootstrap(document, ['demo']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="WelcomeController">
  {{greeting}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `$injector` is used to retrieve object instances as defined by provider, instantiate types, invoke methods, and load modules.

```
var $http = $injector.get('$http');
```

To complete your use-case:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $injector) {
    $scope.myData = [];
    if($scope.loadGrid) {
        var ui_grid = $injector.get('ui-grid');
        ui_grid.load($scope.myData); //`.load` is just a guess, obviously read your docs
    }
});
```

For more information see:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector
- https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection

Comment: That if I want to use the `$http` in the controller. My question is about inject another `module` with directives.

Comment: Yes, `$http` is just an example. Replace `$http` with whatever other module you like.

Comment: _`.load` is just a guess, obviously read your docs_ `ui-grid` I don't think that you can inject module and use it like this. Also, an exception is thrown (see the update of my question)

Comment: Who updavote this answer? It's not even works regardless of the specific module. See the **update** of my question.

Answer (score 0):

In a angularJS for injecting module you should inject it after your module name as you did.

But you have few steps to can use it:

1. Install it with this 2 way `npm` or `bower` like below:

   `npm install angular-ui-grid`

   `bower install angular-ui-grid`
2. Then add a `<script>` to your index.html:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"href="/bower_components/angularui-grid/ui-grid.css" />
   <script src="/bower_components/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js"></script>
   ```

   - If you use `npm`, you should change the source path to`/node_modules/`.

After this steps each module you can have access to you module like below:

`angular.module('my.module', ['ui.grid'])`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it's not what I asked. I know how to inject module to my app. My question is about **dynamic** injection. Please read the question again.

Comment: sorry because of my miss understanding! you can check [angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers](https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers). maybe be useful.